# Sudden Issue displaying embedded tweet in mozilla

Tags: html, css, firefox, twitter, mozilla

One of my websites went online a few weeks back. The design included an embed tweet within a div which displayed properly at that time.

However while checking today, I noticed the embed tweet has moved to the right in Mozilla. Now what's puzzling me is that I didn't even touch the code, so has twitter or Mozilla updated one of their properties???

heres a [link](http://www.whitehousegroup.in/) to my site.

Comment: OK I just noticed that turning of 
       `display:block`
       `margin:10px 0`


in firebug solved the issue
however I cannot simply overwrite the css set by twitter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK the problem is solved finally managed overwriting the css created by twitter.

I simply used the following scc selector

```
    "div_containing_twitter_script" iframe {properties}
```

So if I placed the code in a div with "twitter" as an id the code would be

```
   #twitter iframe {property:value}
```

Nevertheless thanks a lot for trying to help me out...

Answer (score -1):

If Twitter feeds are not showing you can use this following code.

```
    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script> <p></p> <script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script>
new TWTR.Widget({
  version: 2,
  type: 'profile',
  rpp: 5,
  interval: 1000,
  width: 180,
  height: 200,
  theme: {
    shell: {
      background: '#88d4ff',
      color: '#ffffff'
    },
    tweets: {
      background: '#ffffff',
      color: '#333333',
      links: '#00aeef'
    }
  },
  features: {
    scrollbar: false,
    loop: true,
    live: true,
    behavior: 'default'
  }
}).render().setUser('@YourUser').start(); /* Need to change User ID*/
</script>
```

Comment: I also faced the same problem earlier, now i sorted it out.

Comment: It did not help, the stream shows exactly where the embed tweet appeared.

Comment: saswata, his question is the LOCATION of the tweet.

Comment: I visited your link...is it appearing in some other pace now also.. Bcoz i didn't find that.